# Update SQL query by comparing two table

Tags: sql, sql-update, db2

How to update query in sql  column by comparing two tables ? This might be duplicated question, but yet still cannot solve my problem. Any help would be appreciated.

What i've tried so far, but error

```
UPDATE b SET b.STAMP = b.STAMP + 10 FROM TB_FWORKERSCH b,TB_FWORKERCN a 
WHERE a.ISSDATE>='20150401' AND a.UKEY=b.UKEY2 and b.STAMP=0 AND b.IG_SUMINS!=0
```

DB2 Database

Comment: Try UPDATE b SET... and not UPDATE TB_FWORKERSCH b

Comment: tried. error -> The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a valid Command Line Processor command

Comment: AND b.IG_SUMINS<>0 instead of AND b.IG_SUMINS!=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DB2 doesn't allow a JOIN or FROM for an UPDATE clause (this is also not specified in the SQL standard).

You can achieve what you want with a co-related sub-query:

```
UPDATE tb_fworkersch b
  SET stamp = stamp + 10 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM tb_fworkercn a 
              WHERE a.issdate >= '20150401' 
                AND a.ukey = b.ukey2) 
AND b.stamp = 0
AND b.ig_sumins <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MERGE INTO TB_FWORKERSCH b 
USING TB_FWORKERCN a
   ON a.UKEY=b.UKEY2
   AND a.ISSDATE>='20150401' AND b.STAMP=0 AND b.IG_SUMINS<>0
WHEN MATCHED
   THEN UPDATE SET b.STAMP = b.STAMP + 10;
```

Comment: hmm .. error -> An unexpected token "10 FROM TB_FWORKERSCH b INNER JOIN TB_" was found following "B.STAMP = B.STAMP +".

Comment: @user3835327:- Updated my answer. Please check!